# Ignore compilation warnings when using CocoaPods in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

First of all:

```
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

**do not work** for Pods written in Swift, like `Alamofire`. It works only for other Pods, written in Objective-C. How do I block all the warnings?

**UPDATE:**

This has been fixed in CocoaPods version `1.0.0.beta.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no workaround to fix it. It's a CocoaPods known issue and they are working on it, said Alamofire : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/937 
When it will be fixed, you will just have to update CocoaPods by simply install again your gem:

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods
```